# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, hosting

I have created an ASPNetCore3.1 web application using entityframeworkcore5.0.4. I opened an account with GoDaddy and they are now saying they only support version 2.0 which I believe is unsupported.
Any advice on what I need to host this version of asp.netcore3.1?

Many thanks,

Comment: I am slightly confused probably do to lack of experience but I have found a hosting site that supports ASP.Net  4.8 and .Net Core 5.0.3. Does this mean they support ASP.Net Core 3.1 not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Why use GD as your hosting provider? If you can ask for refund, you better change your provider. I personally use Asphostportal, they fully support .net core. You can consider this provider.